# Change view in linked excel with sharepoint list

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Can someone help me how can I change view in Excel, which is connected with Lists in Sharepoint ? This is my VBA code:

```
Sub link_edit_Mode()

Dim mySh As Worksheet
Dim spSite As String

Set mySh = Sheets("one")

Dim src(0 To 1) As Variant

   spSite = " url " 'site name
   src(0) = spSite & "/_vti_bin"
   src(1) = "{lists GUID}" 'GUID

mySh.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, src, True, xlYes, mySh.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

It works, but it gives me the table from sharepoint, which has default view, but I need change this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do small changes in your code (see below)

```
Sub link_edit_Mode()

Dim mySh As Worksheet
Dim spSite As String

Set mySh = Sheets("one")

Dim src(0 To 2) As Variant

   spSite = " url " 'site name
   src(0) = spSite & "/_vti_bin"
   src(1) = "{lists GUID}" 'GUID
   src(2) = "{view GUID}" 

mySh.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, src, True, xlYes, mySh.Range("A1")

End Sub
```